# Python Generic[T] - typehint inherited nested classes

Tags: python, generics, inheritance, python-typing, typechecking

After a few rewrites due to cluttered code, I now have a setup that involves a set of BaseClasses and multiple inherited classes thereof such that

```py
class Base:
  class Nested: ...
  class Nested2: ...
  ...
  class NestedN: ...

class A(Base):
  class Nested(Base.Nested): ...
  class Nested2(Base.Nested2): ...
  ...
  class NestedN(Base.NestedN): ...

class B(Base):
  class Nested(Base.Nested): ...
  class Nested2(Base.Nested2): ...
  ...
  class NestedN(Base.NestedN): ...

class C(Base): 
  ...
```

This suits my needs perfectly in terms of structure, maintainability and readability however it screws up my typehinting - especially when it comes to `Generic`s. More explicitly I would like to create a generic class for all of these inherited classes with proper typing like this:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic

T = TypeVar("T", bound=Base)

class TypeHintedGenericClass(Generic[T]):
    def function_1(obj: T) -> T.Nested2: # E: I can only typehint Base.Nested2 not T.Nested2
        ...

    def function_2(nst: T.Nested) -> T: # E: I can only typehint Base.Nested not T.Nested
        ...
```

My goal is to be able to create generic classes like this:

```py
generic_A = TypeHintedGenericClass[A]
generic_A.function_1(...) # returns A.Nested2 

generic_B = TypeHintedGenericClass[B]
generic_B.function_1(...) # returns B.Nested2
```

I understand that this structure might not be completetly according to the books but it seems to be the most readable and understandable for my (rather large but very repetitive) usecase.

I am open to any suggestions.... Thanks!

Comment: well, there is always the option of simply skipping type-hinting: keep in mind it is optional in Python.

Comment: Thanks for the input but typing is specifically what we want to achieve with a lot of this. Large codebases without it tend to be hard to maintain and debug in my experience.